# Get part of data by d3 in HTML

Tags: html, json, d3.js

```
[
 {
   "name": "000",
   "0passenger": 15,
   "1passenger": 17,
   "2passenger": 1,
   "3passenger": 0,
   "4passenger": 74,
   "5passenger": 35,
   "6passenger": 83,
   "7passenger": 179,
   "8passenger": 278,
   "9passenger": 156,
   "10passenger": 171,
   "11passenger": 9330,
   "12passenger": 162,
   "13passenger": 189,
   "14passenger": 121,
   "15passenger": 106,
   "16passenger": 101,
   "17passenger": 194,
   "18passenger": 233,
   "19passenger": 151,
   "20passenger": 112,
   "21passenger": 18,
   "22passenger": 133,
   "23passenger": 63,
   "passenger": 256404
 },
 {
   "name": "111",
   "0passenger": 17,
   "1passenger": 0,
   "2passenger": 0,
   "3passenger": 0,
   "4passenger": 23,
   "5passenger": 16,
   "6passenger": 29,
   "7passenger": 34,
   "8passenger": 97,
   "9passenger": 62,
   "10passenger": 91,
   "11passenger": 35,
   "12passenger": 39,
   "13passenger": 48,
   "14passenger": 37,
   "15passenger": 45,
   "16passenger": 55,
   "17passenger": 71,
   "18passenger": 98,
   "19passenger": 51,
   "20passenger": 41,
   "21passenger": 41,
   "22passenger": 49,
   "23passenger": 05,
   "passenger": 94397
 },
 {
   "name": "222",
   "0passenger": 8,
   "1passenger": 0,
   "2passenger": 0,
   "3passenger": 0,
   "4passenger": 37,
   "5passenger": 46,
   "6passenger": 52,
   "7passenger": 145,
   "8passenger": 224,
   "9passenger": 122,
   "10passenger": 57,
   "11passenger": 78,
   "12passenger": 72,
   "13passenger": 76,
   "14passenger": 77,
   "15passenger": 36,
   "16passenger": 247,
   "17passenger": 10,
   "18passenger": 192,
   "19passenger": 126,
   "20passenger": 112,
   "21passenger": 174,
   "22passenger": 152,
   "23passenger": 21,
   "passenger": 203246
 }
]
```

I have a passenger data like above one and I want to make a bar graph that shows only the results corresponding to the selected time zone from this data.
In this case, is there a way to get only part of the data when I get data by d3 like getting data of 5~15?
And this is the code of drawing bar graph that shows 'passenger' data. How can I connect these?

```
    function drawBarChart(Num) {
            url = (data address)
  
        d3.csv(url, function (data) {
            data.sort(function (a, b) { return b.passenger - a.passenger; })
    
            x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.bus; }))
            xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.passenger })]);
            yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
            var u = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data);
    
            u.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .merge(u)
                .transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.name); })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.passenger); })
                .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.passenger); })
                .attr("fill", function (d) {
                    if (d.name == Num.toLowerCase()) { return "white"; }
                    else return "black";
                })
            u.exit().remove();
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate you hourly data into an array `byHour` and extract a relevant time range by `slice`:

```js
const grouped = data.map(item => {
  const byHour = Array(24).fill(0).map((_, i) => item[`${i}passenger`] || 0);
  return {name: item.name, total: item.passenger, byHour};
});

const getRange = (fromHour, toHour) => 
  grouped.map(item => ({...item, byHour: item.byHour.slice(fromHour, toHour)}));
```